# How to access controller-level values in a 'contained' directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This is one of two problems.  Either it is a simple scope issue that I'm just not seeing.  Or, I am misusing either controllers and/or directives.

Let's say I have departments, and, on the department update form, I have a shuttle component to select the employees in that department.

I have a controller, something like:

```
app.controller('EmployeeChooserController', function ($scope, $http) {
    ...
    // These two arrays are used in a shuttle component I put into a directive
    $scope.availablePersonnel = [];
    $scope.selectedPersonnel = [];
    // These are populated, as appropriate.  
    // selectedPersonnel[] contains employee objects that are associated with this department
    // availablePersonnel[] contains everyone else
    ...
});
```

The code for the employeeChooser directive looks like:

```
myDirectives.directive('employeeChooser', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            // I need to see availablePersonnel and selectedPersonnel here
            // to manipulate with my shuttle code
            // There are shuttleLeft() and shuttleRight() methods here
        },
        templateUrl: '/snippets/employee-chooser.html'
    }
});
```

The templateURL referenced as employee-chooser.html:

```
<div ng-controller="EmployeeChooserController">       
    <select multiple ng-change="shuttleRight(leftSelect)" ng-model="leftSelect" ng-options='p.id as p.name for p in availablePersonnel track by p.id' >
    </select>
    <select ng-change="shuttleLeft(rightSelect)" ng-model="rightSelect" ng-options='p.id as p.name for p in selectedPersonnel track by p.id'>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to access availablePersonnel and selectedPersonnel in the directive as annotated in the comments.  They are, of course available in $scope of the controller.  Just not sure how to see them in the directive without hacking something ugly together.

Any advice?

Follow Up:
The directive is referred to within a form, something like:

Comment: where have you declared the directive in your template?

Comment: what does `CrewChooserController` controller do? What is need for isolated scope for this? What is shown is not well connected for us to see the bigger layout

Comment: @charlietfl  Sorry, that CrewChooser was a typo.  I was trying to simplify this from a much larger set of code.  I think I'm not well-versed enough in Angular to know if an isolated scope is needed. I certainly don't need it for any other purpose.  What would the alternative be?

Comment: if scope isn't isolated you have full access to controller scope inside `link` function

Comment: In addition to what @charlietfl said above, you should just `require: 'ngModel'` instead of getting the model via attribute. You would access it in the `link` (`postLink`) function as the fourth argument, eg `link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel)`

Answer (score 1):

With credit to @charlietfl and @Phil, the solution was simple.

I simply changed the directive code to:

```
myDirectives.directive('employeeChooser', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ...
        },
        templateUrl: '/snippets/employee-chooser.html'
    }
});
```

Works perfectly and gives the directive everything it needs.

Thanks for the tips!  I'm still trying to wrap my head around the way scope is handled.